# Google Storage Bucket Permission to view object but not to list

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-cloud-storage, roles, deprecated

I created a storage bucket with publicly accessible files. I want to ensure that viewers can view individual objects if they access them directly, but I do not want them to be able to list the contents of the bucket or individual folders.

I created a user called `allUsers`

I looked at the `Storage Object Viewer` role, which is defined as "Read access to GCS objects." After doing some more research, this role does allows listing of the objects in a bucket: "Grants access to view objects and their metadata, excluding ACLs. Can also list the objects in a bucket." - https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#storage-roles

I see another role called `Storage Legacy Object Reader` which is described  as "Read access to objects without listing." - exactly what I need. But it's legacy and given Google's record for surprise announcements I'm expecting this to be deprecated with very short notice.

How to achieve the same permission as `Storage Legacy Object Reader` but in a non-legacy way?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

As [official doc mentionned](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets) :

> Note: **roles/storage.objectViewer** includes permission to list the
>   objects in the bucket. If you don't want to grant listing publicly,
>   use **roles/storage.legacyObjectReader**.

The role `Storage Legacy Object Reader` includes only the permission `storage.objects.get`, so you can consider at least 2 options :

- Use this legacy role, which is not planned to be deprecated, and continues to be recommended by official docs especially to make a [link with ACL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam#acls).
- Create a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) with this unique permission.

Answer (score 0):

I also thought not just **"Storage Legacy Object Reader"** but also other **"Storage Legacy ..." roles** as shown below were deprecated because they contain **the word "Legacy"**:

[image]

But as long as I researched, they are not deprecated even now **"Apr, 2022"** which is **about 2 and half years after you asked this question**.  I guess they are kind of stable roles which are not easily and immediately deprecated.

If you are worried that they are deprecated sooner or later, you can create a custom role following [**this instruction "Creating a custom role"**](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#creating_a_custom_role).